# How do I replace all blank lines with "@"?

Tags: java, list, split, whitespace

Assuming I have a list:

```
List<Strings> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
lines.add("one");
lines.add("");
lines.add("two three");
```

which gives me the following when I convert it to a string i.e. `this.str`:

```
one

two three
```

I am trying to create a method which counts the number of lines, however, it does not recognise the empty line. I have tried doing this:

```
this.str = this.str.replaceAll("\n", "@");
String[] words = this.str.split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

If I were to call `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words)`, I am expecting to get `[one, @, two three]`, however, I am getting `[one@@two three]` instead. How do I solve this?

Comment: Wouldn't the answer depend on the language, which you haven't specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.str` actually contains the string: `one\n\ntwo three`. That's why after executing:
    this.str = this.str.replaceAll("\n", "@");
`this.str` contains now: 'one@@two three`.

The number of `@` is the number of new lines you had in `this.str`.
Now, if you do:

```
String[] words = this.str.split("@");
```

you will get `["one", "", "two three"]`, which is the number of rows you had in the original `this.str`

Comment: Just a side question, if the List contains 2 empty lines instead i.e. 
`lines.add("")` twice and I want to get `['','']`, will the same way as you've proposed work as well?

Comment: yes, looks like that `this.str` you converted from the array for strings will make `\n\n` string.

Comment: In general - for every string you add to `lines` and convert to `this.str`, a `\n` is added at the end of it.

Comment: I've just tried doing the same, but I ended up getting `[]` instead, what is wrong with it?

Comment: please share how you convert that array of string to the str and I will try to help

Comment: I did it this way:
`this.str = this.str.replaceAll("\n", "@");`
`String[] words = this.str.split("@");`
 `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));`
and in my `lines` list I did 
`lines.add("")
lines.add("")`

Comment: I meant - how you converted the `lines` to `this.str`, before you did `replaceAll`? If you want, we can continue in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191758/discussion-between-cheryl-and-galando).

Comment: You'd better hope the original string didn't have an `@`'s in it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the output is correct.

The string **str** have two newline after the word "one".

```
one\n
\n
two three
```

The **+** in the regex:

```
this.str.split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

means *one or more*.
The thing is: **you split after replace the \n char!**, so now you have a single string in the array.

Change this:

```
this.str.split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

with this:

```
this.str.split("@");
```